Prevent empty line in first output of org-babel bash session
In Emacs 28.2 with org-mode 9.5.5 and --no-init-file on Debian 12 the output of the first evaluation of a bash session is polluted by an empty newline.
#+begin_src bash :session c                                                    
echo hi                                                                        
#+end_src                                                                      

#+RESULTS:
|    |
| hi |

Org-mode formats the output as a table. In the shell buffer the following is outputted:
echo hi
rovanion@T14:~$ hi
rovanion@T14:~$ echo 'org_babel_sh_eoe'
org_babel_sh_eoe

Any subsequent evaluations do not have this problem.
#+begin_src bash :session c                                                    
echo hi                                                                        
#+end_src                                                                      

#+RESULTS:
: hi     

The shell output for this latter evaluation looks like
rovanion@T14:~$ echo hi
hi
rovanion@T14:~$ echo 'org_babel_sh_eoe'
org_babel_sh_eoe
rovanion@T14:~$ 

and differs from the first in that there is a prompt before echo hi.
What is the cause of this behavior? Is it repeatable on your machine? Is it possible to work around it?

I can reproduce on 9.5.5, but not on 9.6, so it must have been fixed by some commit in 9.6. Unfortunately, git bisect refuses to work for me between those two, so I cannot pinpoint it any further (easily).

I got git bisect to work and found that this bug was fixed with this commit.
